# symmetry proof of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three  $[N \times N]$ tridiagonal matrices A,B,C with the following properties:

1. The off-diagonal entrees are 1 in all three matrices.
2. $A(1,1)=A(N,N)=-1$,  and $A(i,i)=-2$ for all $i\ne 1,N$.
3. $B(1,1)=B(N,N)=5$  and $B(i,i)=10$ for all $i\ne 1,N$.
4. $C(1,1)=C(N,N)=1.5$  and $C(i,i)=3$ for all $i\ne 1,N$.

I pretty sure that $AB^{-1}C$ should be symmetric, but I want to prove it. Any ideas?